# unable to connect DMS serverless to AWS lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, connectivity, amazon-lightsail, aws-dms

I have two AWS accounts one of which has the DMS serverless replication and another one has the Database in an AWS Lightsail instance. The issue is that I have successfully configured the network peering between both the AWS accounts and also have allowed access to the Lightsail instance through the firewall over all ipv4. But the problem is that when I access the database in the Lightsail instance (in account 2) from aws DMS (in aws account 1) I am getting a timeout error in the network connection. I have tested some experiments, in which first I created a DMS instance with a public IP attached in that case it connected but when I removed its public IP it also gave the same error. And in AWS DMS serverless [as per documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Serverless.Limitations.html) they don't have public IP and are dependent on the VPC endpoint. However, I do not know how to resolve this issue.